# Find a piece of text on a webpage, knowing the name of the elemnt that contains this text

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping, html, element

So there is a dynamic webpage, and all I want is just to find a piece of text on this page, the piece of text, that is under a particular elemnt fn that webpage, how can I do that using c#?

So to clarify the webpage often contains javascript codes as well. The 10bet website has in a way quite simillar webpages, so for instance go there:

1) http://www.10bet.co.uk/sports/soccer/england_premier_league/

2) then choose ANY match and click the blue number on the right of it (eg: +80)

3) then find any bet and try to inspect an element of THE COEFICIENT of that bet, i want to remember this coefiecent and

and that is where I wnat to get using c#

any help will be highly appreciateed.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

The page you've provided uses ajax to load the content (matches).

Find the data source of this (use chrome dev tools & inspect the network tab).

Looks like it's doing a post request to http://www.10bet.co.uk/pagemethods.aspx/UpdateEvents

download data in something like this -

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{       
     var response = webClient.DownloadData(url);
     return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
}
```

If you're parsing html, i recomment HtmlAgilityPack.

There's a lot of ajax going on on that page, so you'll need to break it down into small tasks & proceed from there .

Comment: btw, there's no easy solution to this - if it was a static html page that you were downloading - easy. But given that it's all ajax, you're more likely gonna be parsing json or xml, opposed to pinching html elements.

Answer (score 0):

Firts of all, a website is nothing but plain text that is interpreted diffrently by you browser. All you have to do is start a webclient in C# code and request the website. This can then be saves as a string that you can query.

Another way is to define the website as an XML document. Again using Webclient to request the website and then parse it to an XMLdocument object. Then you can query the desires XML tag / "element name"

here are some helpfull links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx